# Multiple ultrafilter quantifiers

Tags: logic, filters

I'm reading Todorcevic's book Introduction to Ramsey spaces and I stumble on the following use of ultrafilter quantifiers: given a formula $\phi$ with variables $x_1,\dots,x_k$, $\mathcal{U}x_1\dots\mathcal{U}x_k\phi(x_1,\dots,x_k)$. I understood the definition for one variable: $\mathcal{U}x\phi(x)$ iff $\{x:\phi(x)\}\in\mathcal{U}$, but I can't write down the precise definition for the quantifier in two or more variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal Ux_1\mathcal Ux_2\phi(x_1,x_2)$ means that $\{y\mid\mathcal Ux_2 \phi(y,x_2)\}\in\mathcal U$, which means that $\{y\mid\{x\mid\varphi(y,x)\}\in\mathcal U\}\in\mathcal U$.

I think the clarifying example is the definition of the semigroup operation on $\beta\omega$, extending addition of natural numbers we set $$\mathcal U_1+\mathcal U_2=\{A\subseteq\omega\mid \{x\in\omega\mid\{y\in\omega\mid x+y\in A\}\in\mathcal U_2\}\in\mathcal U_1\},$$ or equivalently $$\mathcal U_1+\mathcal U_2=\{A\subseteq\omega\mid\mathcal U_1x\mathcal U_2y\,\, x+y\in A\}.$$